# Create a CHANGELOG from a merge commit listing all the commits of the merged branch (Nestjs + Github Actions + standard-version)

Tags: nestjs

I have integrated standard-version into my nestjs and it works very well as long as I push every single commit directly to main. I created a trigger for GitHub Actions that automatically runs standard-version after each push to the main.

However, when I try to work on a branch where I collect different commits before merging to the main, standard-version no longer works properly.
All my commits have corresponding prefixes but only the last merge commit is visible and all commits from the branch are completely missing in the changelog.

What am I doing wrong? Is there something better than the standard-version for Nestjs that is just as simple?

Here is my package.json

```
  "scripts": {
   ...
    "release": "standard-version"
  },
  ...
  ,
  "standard-version": {
    "commitAll": true
  }
```

And this is how I start it in the github workflow yml:

```
  - name: Run release
    run: npm run release
  - name: Push changes
    run: git push --follow-tags origin main
```

And this what I see:

```
1.6.0 (2023-06-03)
Features
Merge branch 'feature/user-settings' into main (2f54cfk)
1.5.3 (2023-06-03)
```

However, this branch `feature/user-settings` contains many commits with message with feat, fix and chore prefix and a scope like "feat(controller): Add new controller ..."

All this is not visible in the changelog. I thought that standard-version automatically analyses all commits between the created git tags and includes them in the changelog if the prefixes are present. What do I understand wrong and how to do it right? I would like to have the changelog generated automatically. I thought it should be possible to list different changes between tags the standard-version creates automatically, because I have already seen this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. It was in `actions/checkout@v2`. It must be used with `fetch-depth: 0`, otherwise standard-version only sees the last commit.